# Sharepoint Rest API - Apply filter on expanded fields - Status 400

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint

I am using Sharepoint rest API to get specific files in a group of folders. For this, I am applying filter on the expanded field. The problem is when I apply filter, it says the "Field or property does not exist"

I've tried to get the data without applying filter and it's coming correctly. Also, I am able to apply filter on the fields which are not under the expand parameter.

Below code is working in postman:

```
https://sp.foo.net/sites/spdsdfrn/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/abc/2019')/Folders?$expand=Files&$select=Files/Name&$filter=Files/Name eq 'abc.xlsx'
```

Below is the relevant part of the output:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "https://sp.foo.net/sites/spdsdfrn/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/abc/2019/folder1')",
                    "uri": "https://sp.foo.net/sites/spdsdfrn/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/abc/2019/folder1')",
                    "type": "SP.Folder"
                },
                "Files": {
                    "results": [
                        {
                            "__metadata": {
                                "id": "https://sp.foo.net/sites/spdsdfrn/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/abc/2019/folder1/abc.xlsx')",
                                "uri": "https://sp.foo.net/sites/spdsdfrn/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/abc/2019/folder1/abc.xlsx')",
                                "type": "SP.File"
                            },
                            "Name": "abc.xlsx"
                        },
                        {
                            "__metadata": {
                                "id": "https://sp.foo.net/sites/spdsdfrn/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/abc/2019/folder1/def.xlsx')",
                                "uri": "https://sp.foo.net/sites/spdsdfrn/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/abc/2019/folder1/def.xlsx')",
                                "type": "SP.File"
                            },
                            "Name": "def.xlsx"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
.........
.........
..........
```

Below code is not working in postman:

```
https://sp.foo.net/sites/spdsdfrn/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/abc/2019')/Folders?$expand=Files&$select=Files/Name&$filter=Files/Name eq 'abc.xlsx'
```

Below is the error output I am getting with status code 400 (bad request):

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Field or property \"Name\" does not exist."
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen many solutions on the internet and they suggest that it should work in this way. Also, I've seen to check the internal names as they might differ but it's same "Name" in this case.

Is it some bug or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typo:

```
"Field or property \"Names\" does not exist."
```

As your URL references "Name" not "Names".

Your second URL does not have the file type (.xlsx)

```
&$filter=Files/Name eq 'abc'
```

Otherwise...

Your URL includes "/folder". This returns a list of folders. Are you looking for a file in a particular folder, or all files by that name in any folder?

This will return a file in a particular folder:

```
https://sp.foo.net/sites/spdsdfrn/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/abc/2019')/files?$select=Name&$filter=Name eq 'abc.xlsx'
```

Technically speaking... It's a "server relative", not "site relative" URL. But starting with the library name seems to work.

```
https://sp.foo.net/sites/spdsdfrn/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/abc/2019')/Folders
```

probably should be:

```
https://sp.foo.net/sites/spdsdfrn/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/spdsdfrn/Shared Documents/abc/2019')/Folders
```

Comment: Mike - Yes, that was a typo (multiple postman sessions you know), which I've corrected now and yes, I am not looking for file in a particular folder, but all the files in the subfolders inside the folder 2019. That's why I used expand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **GetItems** method in combination with setting **FolderServerRelativeUrl** property and Scope.

**Example code**:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var fileName="abc.xlsx";
    var libraryTitle="Documents";
    var folderRelativeUrl="Shared Documents/abc/2019";
    var viewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='File'>"+fileName+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+libraryTitle+"')/getitems?$select=*,FileDirRef,FileRef"; 
    var query = {  
               'query' : {
                      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                      'ViewXml' : viewXml,
                      'FolderServerRelativeUrl': folderRelativeUrl 
               }
    };

    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(query),
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data.d.results));          
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(err));
            }
     });
});
</script>
```

Or we can use the REST API below.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=File&$expand=File&$filter=FileLeafRef eq 'abc.xlsx'
```

Comment: I'll try the rest api you provided, but any reason why my solution is not working?

Comment: Ok.. the issue with the rest api solution is that it's not specifically searching in the 2019 folder as required.

Comment: You can set FolderServerRelativeUrl to get data in the 2019 folder.